# Combine sbt tasks from different scopes

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I use sbt with the native packager plugin, in order to build Debian packages for our Play 2.2 applications. We use the `debian:publish` in order to upload the packages to our Artifactory server, and the `publish` command to publish the regular Java jars.

I'd like to be able to use the regular `publish` command to published both the jar files and the Debian packages. I think I need to somehow combine the publish task in the `Debian` scope with the regular one in the `Compile` scope, but I can't really find any documentation on how to do that.

I came up with the following code, which works, but seems to me to be the 'wrong' way to do it:

```
publish := { // Also publish deb files
  val value = publish.value
  (publish in Debian).value
}
```

Especially the second line seems wrong, since it's ignoring the value. The `val` is there to quiet a warning, which is another smell.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `triggeredBy`. In your `build.sbt` add following line:

```
publish in Debian <<= (publish in Debian).triggeredBy(publish in Compile)
```

PS. I think the way you did it is also fine. If you're worried about the warning you can assign the result to some `val`.

Comment: I think this looks way better, because it's more descriptive of what I'm actually trying to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: An issue here is that failures in publish in Debian are not propagated.

Answer (score 2):

Here, the `dependsOn` task is appropriate, if you don't care about the return value:

```
publish := publish.dependsOn(publish in Debian).value
```